# How to replace numbers with #

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have an Account number which is 8 digits long. How can i loop through it and replace the numbers with # and only display the last digit?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well i was looking at Salt hash in visual studio, but im curious to see if any one has a better way of going about this?

Comment: you can take that account number as a string and you can use String.Replace method...

Comment: the input is numbers so 12345678 but an account number

Comment: Plenty of answers there ;-) Here is mine, based on regex and negative lookahead :        var reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\d(?!$)");
       var maskedNumber = reg.Replace(NumberFieldDescriptor, "#");

Comment: @ScottAtkinson: Ask another question for your requirement to use an input control which masks the text in a given pattern(like a password-field).

Answer (score 3):

```
int number = 12345678;
String strNumber = number.ToString();
String result = "#######" + strNumber[strNumber.Length - 1];
```

Comment: You could use string.Format("#######{0}", number.ToString()[7]) for efficiency.

Comment: @ChrisGessler: Why should  `string.Format` be more efficient?

Comment: "Strings in .NET" is a long discussion, but the short answer is that string.Format() uses a StringBuilder. I believe your example creates 5 new strings (possibly 4).

Comment: @ChrisGessler: By default `String.Concat`(+) copies pointers and is heavily optimized. It's a myth in .NET that using String.Format or a StringBuilder is faster than a simple `strc=stra+strb`.

Comment: @ChrisGessler - at this scale that would not make a worthwhile optimization.

Comment: Never said "faster".  String.Concat may use pointers, but string concatination always results in a new string.  Each + sign creates a new string.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - The scale is unknown.

Comment: @ChrisGessler: Not necessarily if it's already in the intern string pool. Actually `Concat` or `+` often need even less memory than using a `StringBuilder` (String.Format uses one internally).

Comment: The scale is 1 concat on a <= 10 number. You need 100+ of concats before a StringBuilder becomes relevant.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - like I said, it's a long discussion and the scale is not known from the OP's question.

Comment: After some reading, I discovered that string.Concat (+) now uses a "StringBuilder" under the covers and preallocates the builder based upon the combined lenghs of each string.

Answer (score 1):

```
acct = Regex.Replace(acct, @"\d{7}", "#######");
```

Comment: if that's the static method, `input` goes first, followed by `pattern`

Comment: `Regex.Replace("12345678", @"^\d{7}", "#######");`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Regex.Replace`.

```
    var input = "12345678";
    var pattern = new Regex(@"\d{7}");
    var result = pattern.Replace(input, "#######");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Regex.Replace("01234567", "\\d{7}", "#######")
```

Subsitute in your account number over `"01234567"`

It'll probably be faster, however, to do

```
var result = "#######" + acct.Substring(7)
```

(where `acct` is the account number as a string - if it's an `int` then use `acct.ToString().Substring(7)`)

If you can guarantee that `acct` is 8 characters long.

Comment: Hi, once i have hashed it all, it will display as soon Acct Num: ######## which is fine, but when i come to save it back to DB when changes have been done it going to save the Acct Num as ######## but i need to change it back to what it was...

Comment: @ScottAtkinson, you should edit your question then as it's quite misleading. You are looking for a masked input box.

Comment: @ScottAtkinson - bah? If you need to use the number later then you can't, by definition, get it back after you've stripped off the numbers - you need to be storing it somewhere else un-masked for that.

Comment: Sorry i should of been more specific, i apologise for the inconvience.

Answer (score 1):

**[String Constructor (Char, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx)**

> Initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated
>   by a specified Unicode character repeated a specified number of times.

```
string Number = "12345678";
string str = new string('#', 7) + Number.Substring(Number.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

8 Digit number - show last 1.

```
string acctNumber = "12345678".Substring(7, 1).PadLeft(8, '#');
```

ToString() is also a good choice:

```
acctNumber.ToString("\\#\\#\\#\\#\\#\\#\\#0");
```

Comment: I think its better if you use acctNumber.Lenght in PadLeft. +1 for using PadLeft()

Comment: @hamad - generally yes, but in this case I used method chaining, so I think the current length of acctNumber would be 1.

Comment: At "string acctNumber = acctNumber ...". Isn't it an error there "Use of unassigned local variable ..."?

Comment: @hamad - you're missing the point - Substring(7, 1).PadLeft(8, '#') is the important part here. How the OP gets here, not sure, it's not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could format the number as a string and then remove the first 7 characters from the string using `string.remove(0,7)` then prefix this with "#######". Eg:

```
        int accNumber = 10085697;

        string strAccountNumber=accNumber.ToString();

        string truncatedAccountNumber="#######"+strAccountNumber.Remove(0,7);
```

Answer (score 0):

If account number is `int`

```
int accountNumber = 12345678;
String result = "#######" + accountNumber .ToString()[7];
```

as [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190469/how-to-replace-numbers-with/10190549#10190549) suggested. But if account number is `string`

```
string accountNumber = "12345678";
string result = "#######" + acc.ToCharArray()[accountNumber.Length - 1];
```

Comment: This is the same answer as Tims, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10190549/393908.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko read carefully the answer I gave the option if account number is string as OP hasn't mentioned that it's int

Comment: whose gonna count the `#` better `new string('#', 7)` :)